# how to use pretrained googlenet and alexnet in keras

Tags: python

i am working on googlenet .Can someone tell me that how to use pretrained googlenet and alexnet in python using keras. There is too much material regarding VGG and RESNET but i am not understanding how to use pretrained googlenet and alexnet

Comment: In which form you can find the pre-trained model of VGG and RESNET?

Comment: https://github.com/TannerGilbert/Tutorials/blob/master/Keras-Tutorials/9.%20Using%20pretrained%20models/Keras%20%239%20Using%20the%20pretrained%20Models.ipynb

Comment: It is pretty straight forward, they just import the model and they apply to the test image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the GoogleNet it is recommended [to follow these instructions](https://gogul.dev/software/flower-recognition-deep-learning). In essence, in the following link it is described analytically how can you implement in your project different pre-trained models. You modify your option using the `configuration.json` file.

```
# load the user configs
with open('conf/conf.json') as f:    
   config = json.load(f)
```

and the .json file:

```
{
 "model"           : "inceptionv3",
 "weights"         : "imagenet",
 "include_top"     : false,

 ...
 ...
```

}

Regarding the `AlexNet` you can find the weights and code to use [in here](https://github.com/heuritech/convnets-keras#get-the-weights-of-the-pre-trained-networks).

Comment: thank you but i don't  need VGG .I need googlenet and alexnet

Comment: i have already go through that link you provided but no explanation regarding alexnet

Comment: I add also some explanation for the AlexNet case.

Answer (score 3):

For Googlenet you can use this model.
[GoogLeNet in Keras](https://gist.github.com/joelouismarino/a2ede9ab3928f999575423b9887abd14).
For Alexnet [Building AlexNet with Keras](https://www.mydatahack.com/building-alexnet-with-keras/).
The problem is you can't find imagenet weights for this model but you can train this model from zero.
The only pretrained model on keras are:

Xception,
VGG16,
VGG19,
ResNet, ResNetV2,
InceptionV3,
InceptionResNetV2,
MobileNet,
MobileNetV2,
DenseNet,
NASNet

I hope I have helped you

Comment: i want to train on my own dataset. NO need of imagenet

Comment: so you can use this model.

Comment: Thank you so much.You help me alot

Comment: i think i help you in the same way.Just +1 on my answer it would have been a thank you.